# How is the size of the std::array calculated in the template

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdef>
#include <iostream>
 
// printArray is a template function
template <class T, std::size_t size> // parameterize the element type and size
void printArray(const std::array<T, size>& myArray)
{
    for (auto element : myArray)
        std::cout << element << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
 
int main()
{
    std::array myArray5{ 9.0, 7.2, 5.4, 3.6, 1.8 };
    printArray(myArray5);
 
    std::array myArray7{ 9.0, 7.2, 5.4, 3.6, 1.8, 1.2, 0.7 };
    printArray(myArray7);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help understand how the size of the array is calculated by the function template.

Comment: do you understand how the template gets to know what `T` is?

Comment: What is understood is T is referring to the type of the datatype, based on which the std::array is being defined here...
But what i have failed to understand is how the size of the array is being stored in the variable size[std::size]

Comment: `std::array myArray5` is actually `std::array<double, 5> myArray5`...

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Comment: Agreed @Jarod42, but how is the size of the myArray5 being stored in the  std::size

Comment: See how _template argument deduction_ works. Both `T` and `size` are deduced from function arguments. It's the same as if you called `printArray<double,5>(myArray5);`.

Comment: `5` (`std::size_t N`) is "stored" in `std::array` in similar way than `double` (`typename T`) is. it belongs to the type.

Comment: The template function doesn't calculate the size of the array.   The compiler creates an instantiation the function that accepts a `std::array<T, size>` for each specified type `T` (`double` in both your examples)  and `size` (`5` for `myArray5` and `7` for `myArray7`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `std::array` is a template. When you write

```
std::array myArray5{ 9.0, 7.2, 5.4, 3.6, 1.8 };
```

Then Class Template Argument Deduction ([CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), deduction guides for `std::array` can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides)) is applied to infer that `myArray5` is of type `std::array<double,5>`. That is where the size is "calculated".

Then when you call the function template:

```
printArray(myArray5);
```

The template arguments are deduced from the function parameter (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)). `myArray5` is `std::array<double,5>`, hence `T == double` and `size == 5`.

Comment: The deduction guide for `std::array`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function template, you can provide template arguments explicitly:

```
printArray< double, 5 >(myArray5);
```

If you don't provide them, a compiler tries to *deduce* them according to the type of the passed function argument. In your case, the passed argument `myArray5` has the type `std::array<double,5>`. Consequently, a compiler deduces `T` to `double` and `size` to `5`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear which aspect of array size you are asking about?
Size of the array itself, or the size of the data types resolution.

But with my best guess let me explain both.

C++ is a statically typed language. Which means that the data types of any variable, including templated types are  resolved during compilation time.

Right at the point where you are defining the template typed array,

```
std::array myArray5{ 9.0, 7.2, 5.4, 3.6, 1.8 };
```

At compile-time, C++ sees individual element, say `9.0`, based on the default literal-type associates that to `double` types, and hence forth makes an array of `doubles`.

Hope that helps you understand how to reason about size of each elements in an array. And the total size is just simple multiplication of number of elements in it.

Now, the I know better what you are asking, the default array constructor is [std::array<T, N>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), since, we already know how many elements you are passing to array, the corresponding arguments are filled. Where T being datatype, and N being some fixed size data (which you have already provide `{ 9.0, 7.2, 5.4, 3.6, 1.8 } = 5`), which can be resolved in the compile time.

Comment: I am referring to the below snippet, where we are calculating the size of array which is passed as an argument.
```
template <class T, std::size_t size> // parameterize the element type and size
void printArray(const std::array<T, size>& myArray)
{
    for (auto element : myArray)
        std::cout << element << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @Virenmahajan refresh my answer.